# pgfplots: How to create heatmap with date as x-axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

Assumed we want to draw a nice heatmap in `pgfplots` with `date` as `x-axis`.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=plots]

    \begin{axis}[
                 view={0}{90},
                 shader=interp,
                 mesh/ordering=x varies,
                 mesh/cols=3,
                ]

    \addplot3[surf] coordinates {
        (0,0,50)  (1,0,50)  (2,0,50)
        (0,1,50)  (1,1,100)  (2,1,50)
        (0,2,50)  (1,2,50)  (2,2,50)
    };

    \end{axis}

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the current state]

---

**Description of the issue:**

As you can see, currently the values are based on simple `x`, `y`, `z` coordinates at 9 different positions so far.

However, I've got a huge amount of data consisting of the following structure:

```
Date;                   Date_decimal;   1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10
2019-06-01 12:00:00;    0.000;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;2;2
2019-06-01 12:05:00;    0.083;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;3;3
2019-06-01 12:10:00;    0.167;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;4;4
2019-06-01 12:15:00;    0.250;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;5;5
2019-06-01 12:20:00;    0.333;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;6;6
2019-06-01 12:30:00;    0.417;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;7;7
2019-06-01 12:35:00;    0.500;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;8;8
2019-06-01 12:40:00;    0.583;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;9;9
2019-06-01 12:45:00;    0.667;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;10;10
2019-06-01 12:50:00;    0.750;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;11;11
```

Explanation of the table: First column serves the real `date`, second column serves the date as `decimal_date` (unit: hours), rest of the table is just `y-columns` including a `z-value` for each heatmap coordinate. Furthermore, the included numbers in the first row `1, 2, 3, ... , 10` provide the real index numbers of each column.

Therefore I want to use the following scheme:

- `date`-value or optionally `date_decimal` (unit: decimal hours) should be used as `x`-axis; in case it is more easy to implement `date_decimal`, just skip or throw out the `date`-column (= 10 pcs)
- `y`-axis should be the column index numbers of each table column (1, 2, ... , 10); I wrote it down into the first row for better understanding (= 10 pcs)
- `z`-axis (colored) should be the corresponding value in each cell of the heatmap coordinates (= 100 pcs)

How can I modify the upper diagram, so `x` will be taken as a `date axis` while preserving the matrix structure of the raw data? The real data table contains 2000 rows and 2000 columns, so it wouldn't be possible to rearrange it that easy. :-)

In case it could appear too complicated to use the real `date` column as `x-axis`, one could simply use the `decimal_date`-column instead while throwing out the `date`-column. I have posted another question about this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/501319).

I fear the biggest challenge is to hand over the current data structure to `pgfplots`.

---

**Screenshot of the desired state:**

In the end it could look like this for example:

[image: Screenshot of the desired state]

Comment: Are the y-value in your real data really continouus 1,2,3...? (and so actually equal to the row index?)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, they are. Every column has a specific column name from 1 up to 10. Column name is absolutely equal to the row index.

Comment: and so with 2000 columns the y values would go from 1 to 2000?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Exactly! :-)

Comment: if I understand the problem correctly, then every row `x z1,z2,z3, ...` should "expand" into 10 rows of the type `x i zi`. I don't think that pgfplots can do it by default, and while one could perhaps tweak the data with pgfplotsread, it looks more like a task for a lua (or some other language) script.

Comment: One way that most likely works is to read the table and to write out a table along the lines @UlrikeFischer suggest, namely for each column `z1`, `z2`, ... in the original table you create a new row. I have done something of this sort in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458903/121799), the relevant code is the one after `\begin{document}`, in particular the stuff around `\immediate\openout\myoutput`. But I also agree with Ulrike that LaTeX is not necessarily made for this, a simple perl script may spare you from a lot headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have adapted [my simpler answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502719/44467) for this scenario. It relies on the use of `lualatex`, enabled `shell-escape`, and the manual tuning of some parameters in the script. These parameters are

- `ycols` is the number of columns with (different) y-data of the same length at the beginning of the file. In this case 1. It can be zero, then the `y` output data counts from 1 to the number of `y` values.
- `xrows` is the number of rows with different types of x values. In this case 2. It can be zero, then the `x` output data counts from 1 to the number of `x` values.
- `delimiter` is the pattern-matching variable for separating the matrix entries. I am not really familiar with `lua`, but `[^;]+` works for semicolons and `%S+` works for whitespaces.
- `del_out` is the delimiter written to the new output file, here a semicolon `;`.

Furthermore, lines with too few or too many data entries are detected. It is assumed that the first data line is the correct one.

The `ycols+1`th line of the input data is read in order to extract the number of `y` values. Table headings of the `x` data are optional. Hence, the input data can be in the original format (even with additional entries).

```
Date; nonsense;entries; Date_decimal;   1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10
2019-06-01 12:00:00;    0.000;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;2;2
2019-06-01 12:05:00;    0.083;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;3;3
```

But it can also contain the plain `y` values (intendation is done just for a better look). Both work.

```
                                        1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10
2019-06-01 12:00:00;    0.000;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;2;2
2019-06-01 12:05:00;    0.083;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;3;3
```

The reformatted data looks like this:

```
x1;x2;y1;z
2019-06-01 12:00:00;0.000;1;0.083
2019-06-01 12:00:00;0.000;2;0.25
2019-06-01 12:00:00;0.000;3;0.25
2019-06-01 12:00:00;0.000;4;0.2
2019-06-01 12:00:00;0.000;5;0.22
```

Note that all leading and trailing whitespaces are removed for a more compact file. Two different `x` data types are present in this data, one can choose afterwards whatever is more suitable. For simplicity, I have chosen the numerical value in the row `x2`, but the date is also accessible in `x1` and can be plotted with the `dateplot` library.

By the call of `\directlua{rewrite_mat("data2.dat","out.txt")}`, the matrix in `data2.txt` is rewritten into `out.txt` in the `pgfplots`-compatible vector format.

The complete code (including the matrix data) comes here:

```
%!Tex program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents,luacode}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.dat}
some;data;doesn't;matter;               1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10
2019-06-01 12:00:00;    0.000;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;2;2
2019-06-01 12:05:00;    0.083;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;3;3
2019-06-01 12:10:00;    0.167;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;4;4
2019-06-01 12:15:00;    0.250;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;5;5
2019-06-01 12:20:00;    0.333;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;6;6
2019-06-01 12:30:00;    0.417;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;7;7
2019-06-01 12:35:00;    0.500;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;8;8
2019-06-01 12:40:00;    0.583;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;9;9
2019-06-01 12:45:00;    0.667;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;10;10
2019-06-01 12:50:00;    0.750;          0.083;0.25;0.25;0.2;0.22;0.45;0.6;0.5;11;11
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents}{mat-rewrite.lua}
\begin{luacode}
function rewrite_mat(infilename, outfilename)
  -- open input and output files
  infile  = io.open( infilename, "r")
  outfile = io.open(outfilename, "w")

  -- rest-of-line comments and table delimiters
  -- commentchars='#!' not yet implemented
  delimiter="[^;]+"
  del_out = ";"
  --delimiter="%S+"
  --del_out  =" "

  -- number of columns with y values and rows with x values
  ycols = 1
  xrows = 2

  -- initialize arrays for x/y/z values
  yvals={}
  xvals={}
  zvals={}
  xvals[1] = {}
  yvals[1] = {}
  for i=2,xrows do
    xvals[i] = {}
  end
  for i=2,ycols do
    yvals[i] = {}
  end

  -- initialize counters for numbers of x/y values (matrix size)
  -- can be used later for 'mesh rows' and 'mesh cols'
  ynum = 0
  xnum = 0 - ycols

  -- count the number of y values first
  i = 0
  for line in infile:lines() do
    i = i+1
    if i == ycols +1 then
      t={}                             -- make a table from the current line
      length=0
      for v in line:gmatch(delimiter) do
        length = length + 1
        t[length]=v:gsub("^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1") -- leading and trailing whitespaces removed
      end

      ynum = length - xrows

      break
    end
  end

  infile:close()
  infile  = io.open( infilename, "r")

  -- read the matrix
  for line in infile:lines() do
    t={}                               -- make a table from the current line
    length=0
    for v in line:gmatch(delimiter) do
      length = length + 1
      t[length]=v:gsub("^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1") -- leading and trailing whitespaces removed
    end 

    xnum = xnum + 1                    -- count number of x values (number of lines minus ycols)
                                       -- first lines: store y values
    if (xnum < 1) or ((xnum == 1) and (ycols == 0)) then        
      if length < ynum then
        tex.error("Not enough y values in line " .. xnum + ycols .. ": expected " .. ynum .. ", but got " .. length) -- invoke error
      end
      for y=1,ynum do
        if ycols == 0 then
          yvals[1][y] = t[length-ynum+y]
        else 
          yvals[xnum+ycols][y] = t[length-ynum+y]
        end
      end
    end  

    if xnum >= 1 then                                -- all other lines: store x and z values
      if length < (xrows+ynum) then
        tex.error("Not enough x/z values in line " .. xnum + ycols .. ": expected " .. xrows .. "+" .. ynum .. ", but got " .. length) -- invoke error
      end
      if length > (xrows+ynum) then
        tex.error("Too many x/z values in line " .. xnum + ycols .. ": expected " .. xrows .. "+" .. ynum .. ", but got " .. length) -- invoke error
      end

      if xrows == 0 then
        xvals[1][xnum]=xnum
      else
        for i=1,xrows do
          xvals[i][xnum] = t[i]
        end
      end
      for y=1,ynum do
        index = ynum*(xnum-1)+y
        zvals[index]=t[y+xrows]
      end
    end
  end

  infile:close()

  -- write data
  if xrows == 0 then
    outfile:write("x1" .. del_out)
  else
    for i=1,xrows do
      outfile:write("x" .. i .. del_out)
    end
  end
  if ycols == 0 then
    outfile:write("y1" .. del_out)
  else
    for i=1,ycols do
      outfile:write("y" .. i .. del_out)
    end
  end
  outfile:write("z" .. "\string\n")

  -- write data
  for x = 1,xnum do
    for y = 1,ynum do
        print(xnum)
        print(xvals)
        print(xvals[1])
        print(xvals[1][x])
      if xrows == 0 then
        outfile:write(xvals[1][x] .. del_out)
      else
        for i=1,xrows do
          outfile:write(xvals[i][x] .. del_out)
        end
      end
        print(xnum)
      if ycols == 0 then
        outfile:write(yvals[1][y] .. del_out)
      else
        for i=1,ycols do
          outfile:write(yvals[i][y] .. del_out)
        end
      end
      outfile:write(zvals[(x-1)*ynum+y] .. "\string\n")
    end
  end

  outfile:close()

end  
\end{luacode}
\end{filecontents}
% load function
\input{mat-rewrite.lua}
\begin{document}
\directlua{rewrite_mat("data2.dat","out.txt")}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[mesh/ordering=y varies, unbounded coords=jump,colorbar,title={data from infrared measurements},view={0}{90},xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,colorbar style={xlabel=$^\circ\mathrm{C}$,xticklabel pos=upper,xlabel style={yshift=.22cm}}]
\addplot3[surf,mesh/rows=10,mesh/cols=10] 
  table[col sep = semicolon,
        x = x2, y = y1, z = z
       ] {out.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output of this data:

[image: example output image]

Comment: Wow, incredible! Did you run this in terminal?

Comment: @Dave No, not really. just in lualatex. But with `print(string/variable)` you can output something in the log and with `tex.print(...)` you can write in the final document. That is enough for debugging. :)
I hope that it works also for other data (larger etc.).

Comment: @Dave see the edited solution. It can handle your original data structure now, but also a plain z matrix (as many x or y values as you like, even zero)